# Navigation does not open in Cordova Angular App after using Hardware Back Button

Tags: android, angular, cordova

We have a Webhosted Angular App that we load in a Cordova App and encounter a problem with navigation (nav-Element with *ngIf) after using the Android Back Button.

For example:
**Case 1:**

- Use buttons and links for navigation in app
- Use a back link within the Angular application to go back to the Home Screen
- Nav does open normally, that's fine

**Case 2:**

- Navigate in app
- Use the Hardware Back Button of the Android Device to go back to the Home Screen
- Nav does not open, other links/buttons still work

Here is how we load the Angular App

Cordova index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: ... 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Loading Application</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <a id="bkpLink" href="...">
          <div class="app">
              <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                  <p class="event listening">...</p>
                  <p class="event received">...</p>
              </div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Cordova index.js

```
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
    },
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');

        // Here, we redirect to the Angular web app.
        var targetUrl = "...";
        window.location.replace(targetUrl);
},
    // Note: This code is taken from the Cordova CLI template.
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};

app.initialize();
```

The header in the Angular app includes a link to open the menu-control (onToggle())

```
<div class="header-wrapper row w-100 justify-content-center flex-shrink-0 d-flex">
    <div class="col-2 align-self-center p-2 header-sidemenu-toggle" (click)="onToggle()">
        <a id="header-collapsible-sidebar-btn">
            <span class="icon-menu-toggle"><fa-icon [icon]="faBars"></fa-icon></span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-10 header-title-wrapper">
        <span class="header-title">{{title}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
<menu-control></menu-control>
```

In the Header Component:

```
  onToggle() {
      this.interactionService.toggleSidemenu();  // --> toggles showMenu
  }
```

The MenuControl.html contains the nav-Element contained within the *ngIf

```
<div class="row sidebar-container" *ngIf="showMenu">
    <nav id="sidebar-collapsible" class="sidebar-wrapper">
        <div *ngFor="let mainMenu of mainMenuConfig"> <!-- main Category: foreach -->
            <div class="sidebar-category-wrapper nav flex-column nav-pills">
                <div class="row sidebar-category">
                    <div *ngIf="mainMenu.i18nLabel">{{mainMenu.i18nLabel}}</div>
                    <div *ngIf="!mainMenu.i18nLabel">{{mainMenu.label}}</div>
                </div>
                <div class="nav-link sidebar-item-wrapper" *ngFor="let subMenu of getSubMenu(mainMenu)" (click)="onSubMenuSelect()" [routerLink]="[subMenu.path]" routerLinkActive="active"> <!-- sub menu: foreach -->
                    <div class="row sidebar-item">
                        <div class="col-12 sidebar-item-link-wrapper">
                            <a class="sidemenu-item-link">
                                <span *ngIf="subMenu.i18nLabel">{{subMenu.i18nLabel}}</span>
                                <span *ngIf="!subMenu.i18nLabel">{{subMenu.label}}</span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Lastly, here is my package.json for the cordova app, in case the plugins cause problems

```
{
    ...
    "dependencies": {
        "cordova-android": "^7.1.4",
        "cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.2.0",
        "cordova-plugin-honeywell-barcode-scanner": "0.0.12",
        "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^3.2.0",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
        "cordova-set-version": "^9.0.2",
        "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": "^8.1.0"
    },
    "cordova": {
        "plugins": {
            "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
            "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
            "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": {
                "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
            },
            "cordova-plugin-honeywell-barcode-scanner": {}
        },
        "platforms": [
            "android"
        ]
    },
    ...
}
```